# Insert array as column in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I want to insert each element from an array as the rows of a column.

Example:

array = [1,2,3,2];

the result will be:

```
column1 | 
---------
    1   |  
    2   |  
    3   |  
    2   |
```

I tried out the following code below in my Node.js file but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var array = [1,2,3,2]; 

var queryString = "INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUES ((${array.map((v,i) => `${i+1}`).join(',')}) RETURNING *";

    db.query(queryString, array, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use a package like [sqlstring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlstring) to ease the query creation and prevent nasty SQL injections. In any case the resulting SQL query should look like;

`INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (2);`

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 2];
const values = numbers.map (x => `(${x})`).join (', ');
const query = `INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUES ${values};`;
```

Comment: How do I do the same for update? Do I need a forEach loop?